# How do I convert all of my SE accounts from Facebook to Google?

Tags: support, user-accounts, openid

How can I change my login on all Stack Exchange sites to Google rather than Facebook?

Answer (score 2):

Go to your profile and select **my logins**

Here you can remove ones you don't want and add ones you do want -

[image]